# I am getting the following error while seeding the database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, backend

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5569P.png)

I was expecting that the following data should be seeded in the database.

```
using API.Entities;

namespace API.Data
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(StoreContext context)
        {
            if (context.Products.Any()) 
               return;

            var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product
                    {
                        Name = "Angular Speedster Board 2000",
                        Description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                        Price = 20000,
                        PictureUrl = "/images/products/sb-ang1.png",
                        Brand = "Angular",
                        Type = "Boards",
                        QuantityInStock = 100
                    },
            }

            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                context.Products.Add(product);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 7), @p1='?' (Size = 205), @p2='?' (Size = 28), @p3='?' (Size = 28), @='?' (DbType = Int32), @p6='?' (Size = 6)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Products" ("Brand", "Description", "Name", "PictureUrl", "Price", "QuantityInStock", "Type")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);
      SELECT "Id"
      FROM "Products"
      WHERE changes() = 1 AND "rowid" = last_insert_rowid();
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'API.Data.StoreContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for det
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'table Products has no column named QuantityInStock'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection conne
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllCh
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Fu
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for det
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'table Products has no column named QuantityInStock'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection conne
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllCh
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Fu
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
fail: Program[0]
      A problem occurred during migration
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for det
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'table Products has no column named QuantityInStock'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection conne         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllCh         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Fu         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
         at API.Data.DbInitializer.Initialize(StoreContext context) in C:\Users\Ekram\ReStore\API\Data\DbInitializer.cs:line 216         at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Ekram\ReStore\API\Program.cs:line 40
```

Comment: Have you **read** the error message? *'table Products has no column named QuantityInStock'.* - you cannot set a column that doesn't exist....